# Yargs.argv unresolved variable in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, code-completion

[image]

I'm new to NodeJS, I've installed yargs already but it argv can not be recognized. Any idea why?!

Comment: This is your editor, correct? Which likely either doesn't know about introspecting required files, or isn't able to introspect it. That's an issue with dynamic languages--but it's not a programming error. If you need help with your *editor* you need to say what editor you're using, versions, all the normal stuff. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: I'm using Webstorm 2018.1.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The properties are created dynamically, that's why WebStorm is not able to resolve them during static code analysis.

To work out the issue, you need installing `yargs` typings (`@types/yargs`): hit `Alt+Enter` on `"yargs"` in `require("yargs")`, choose *Install Typescript definitions for better type information*:

[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

This should help:

[image]